# How to edit a received xml file and send over http with php?

Tags: php, xml, rest

I'm have to build a "simple" application that will reads an xml file, prompts a user to choose a "response activity" in relation to what's on that file and send the whole thing (what was loaded + the activity chosen by the user) to a client over http in a new xml file.

So my questions is:
how can i add what's been loaded as well as the user chosen response activity onto a new xml file? and how do i send it to anyaddress.com?

i've also been told to use rest webservices, and although i have found a lot of information and examples online, nothing seem to be relevant to what i'm trying to do.

As you may have guessed, i'm new to all this. here' what i've done so far:

```
<?php
//reader.php
// Load the xml file and show what's on it
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xmlfile.xml')
or die("Could not open file!<hr /> ");

foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
    foreach($child->children() as $young) {
        echo $young->getName() . ": " . $young . "<br />";
    }
}

// call the activity list according to what's on the xml file
if ($child->ACTIVITY == 'activity import') {
    echo "<br/>" . file_get_contents('interface.php');
}   
elseif($child->ACTIVITY == 'activity import special'){
    echo "<br/>" . file_get_contents('interface1.php');
}
elseif($child->ACTIVITY == 'activity export'){
    echo "<br/>" . file_get_contents('interface2.php');
}
else {
    echo "<br/>" . 'incorrect activity';
}

// print the selected activity on page
if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
    $selected_radio = $_POST['group1'];
    print $selected_radio;
}


?>
```

this is one of the 3 forms i have for user input interface2.php

```
<form name="serv1" action="reader.php" method="POST">
<div align="left"><br>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="OUTBOUND"> OUTBOUND<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="DONTPROCESS" checked> DON'T PROCESS<br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Return">
</div>
</form>
```

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform edits on an XML file e.g. with [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/simplexml) or with [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/dom).

You could post the result to another server with [`CURL`](http://php.net/curl).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. i've played around with simpleXML and i can create different xml elements and echo them on my browser. But do you know how i could use the elements i already have from my first xml document and save them in another one? or maybe just add another node to the existing one?

Comment: `simplexml_load_file` and `simplexml_load_string` load an existing document, which then can be edited like you created an empty one.